# Laravel 4 Display ads to load any pictures from another table

Tags: php, laravel, ads

I have a problem with displaying data from the form. He wants to load the data from two tables joined the foreign key.
I do not know what I'm doing wrong because I Chaly time returns the message:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$file
```

offers tabel:

```
id
user_id
title
...
```

photosofoffers tabel:

```
id
offer_id <- primary key offers.id
file (url photos)
...
```

my view:

```
@foreach($offers as $offer)
{{ HTML::image($offer->photosofoffers()->file, $offer->title, array('width'=>'50')) }}
```

my model Offer:

```
    protected $fillable = array('id_category','user_id', 'title', 'description', 'price', 'availability');

    public static $rules = array(
            'id_category'=>'required|integer',
            'title'=>'required|min:2',
            'description'=>'required|min:2',
            'price'=>'required|numeric',
            'availability'=>'integer'

        );


    public function photosofoffers(){

        return $this->hasMany('Photosofoffer');
    }


    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category');
    }


}
```

my model Photosofoffer

```
<?php

class Photosofoffer extends Eloquent {
    public function offer(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Offer');

    }

    public function offers() {
        return $this->hasMany('Offer');
    }

}
```

**How to display ads to load any pictures from another table?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hasMany` means there are many photos of one offer. Therefore is it wise to call `$something->photosofoffer()->photo` ? If the return is an object, you'll definitely get an error.

First do `dd($offer->photosofoffers())` or `dd($offer->photosofoffers)` to see what's happening. Then, if the object is properly being derived, You need to check loop through it. like `@foreach($offer->photosofoffers as $photo) your loop of diplaying image @endforeach`.

If there is nothing being derived, change the Controller function where you collect the actual `$offer` and make it `Model::with('photoofoffers')->get() or first()`

That should clear this up.

Hope this helps.

YK.